# Filter data in Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object.

```js
var Data = [{ datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018", dermatologist: "Canfield", id: 4021, owner_name: "John Doe", pet_name: "Dog", score: 37 }, { datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018", dermatologist: "Nicky barown", id: 4022, owner_name: "Carlos", pet_name: "Cat", score: "57" }, { datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018", dermatologist: "Canfield", id: 4023, owner_name: "James", pet_name: "Parrot", score: 50 }]
```

How to fetch data by a dermatologist from an object.

I'm trying the following code.

```
var result = Data['dermatologist']
```

But I got only one record.

I want all objects which contain the same dermatologist as.

```
  {   "datetime": "03:48 PM 10/31/2018",
      "dermatologist": "Canfield",
       "id": 4021,
      "owner_name": "John Doe",
      "pet_name": "Dog",
      "score": 37
    },

    {
      "datetime": "03:48 PM 10/31/2018",
      "dermatologist": "Canfield",
      "id": 4023,
      "owner_name": "James",
      "pet_name": "Parrot",
      "score": 50
    }
```

Comment: `Date` !== `Data`

Comment: You want all the dermatologists names?

Comment: That object isn't remotely valid JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, @NinaScholz I Edited the question.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: can't you just do this?
Data.forEach(el=>{console.log(el.dermatologist)});

Comment: @Muddasir23 — After your latest edit, the JS data structure **still** won't compile. You need to provide a real [mcve].

Comment: the wanted result makes no sense with the given description. what do you take to get a result? please add all information to the question.

Comment: I edited the question, also got the solutions. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you want to filter the array by known value of a specific key, then you coukd take the property and check against the value for a filtered result set.

Techniques used:

- An [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) for data and
- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for filtering by using an
- [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with a
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the property `dermatologist` of each object and a check with
- [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) and the wanted value.

```js
var data = [{ datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018", dermatologist: "Canfield", id: 4021, owner_name: "John Doe", pet_name: "Dog", score: 37 }, { datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018", dermatologist: "Nicky barown", id: 4022, owner_name: "Carlos", pet_name: "Cat", score: "57" }, { datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018", dermatologist: "Canfield", id: 4023, owner_name: "James", pet_name: "Parrot", score: 50 }],
    result = data.filter(({ dermatologist }) =>  dermatologist === "Canfield");

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it's easy for me to implement and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map()` with object destructuring to get the `dermatologist` array:

```js
var Data = [{
      datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018",
      dermatologist: "Canfield",
      id: "4021",
      owner_name: "John Doe",
      pet_name: "Dog",
      score: "37"
    },
    {
      datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018",
      dermatologist: "Nicky barown",
      id: "4022",
      owner_name: "Carlos",
      pet_name: "Cat",
      score: "57"
    },
    {
      datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018",
      dermatologist: "Canfield",
      id: "4023",
      owner_name: "James",
      pet_name: "Parrot",
      score: "50"
    }
  ];
var dermatologists = Data.map(({dermatologist}) => dermatologist);
console.log(dermatologists);
```

Comment: The data structure in the question is invalid, so you've had to guess at what the real data structure is. What you have can't be what the OP has because they said that `var result = Date['dermatologist']` returns one record.

Comment: I think OP just guessed that because you see that the variable name is `Date` and OP has given the structure with variable name `data`

Comment: @Quentin I think anyone can determine OP meant to write `Data` just by looking at the code.

Comment: @Roj — It seems fairly obvious up until you get to the bit in the question where `var result = Data['dermatologist']` successfully gets one record.

Comment: @Quentin true. But there's nothing wrong with asking for clarification or pushing someone in the right direction by giving better alternatives rather than shutting them down.

Comment: @Roj — I'm all in favour of asking for clarification in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON object needs to be edited so that it can be parsed correctly. I have assumed that your `Data` variable is an array of JSON objects, each of which has a property `dermatologist`. You can access any of the array elements like so: `Data[i].dermatologist`

```js
var Data =   [{
      datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018",
      dermatologist: "Canfield",
      id: "4021",
      owner_name: "John Doe",
      pet_name: "Dog",
      score: "37"
    },
    {
      datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018",
      dermatologist: "Nicky barown",
      id: "4022",
      owner_name: "Carlos",
      pet_name: "Cat",
      score: "57"
    },
    {
      datetime: "03:48 PM 10/31/2018",
      dermatologist: "Canfield",
      id: "4023",
      owner_name: "James",
      pet_name: "Parrot",
      score: "50"
    }
  ];
  
  console.log(Data[0].dermatologist);   //Canfield
  console.log(Data[1].dermatologist);   //Nicky barown
  //alternatively:
  console.log(Data[2]["dermatologist"]);   //Canfield
```

Now it is easy to set up a `for loop` to iterate through all of the elements and do whatever is required to each element.